# ASP.NET webconfig file error

Tags: asp.net, web-config, devexpress

I am using devexpress controller in asp.net . When I deployed to azure app service it was showing error. Then I added . Now after the deployment it is still showing different error. Can anyone help me on that please ?

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Any dll present for DevExpress in the application?

Comment: yes.. App_Lincenses.dll .

Comment: Check its property on properties window.. and see Copy local is true.. and some similar properties of that file so that it copies itself while building the application..